# Flutter android release stuck on splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, release-builds

Flutter android release build is stuck on splash screen.

I have tried by cleaning project `flutter clean`. But still it got stuck on splash screen. I have also used `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` before executing the `runApp()`. Still it stuck on splash screen. Also haven't found error logs that can be resolved.

It is not happening with debug version or when I run with `flutter run --release`. The app is running smoothly in `flutter run --release`.

I'm using flutter 1.22.0 & VSCode 1.49.3. Testing & releasing for android.

I'm stuck with this last 3 days. It would be very helpful if anyone can help me.

Comment: try with the latest version of flutter and run `flutter run --release -v` to see the logs.

Comment: The app is not stucking on splash screen when running with `flutter run --release`. It is only stucking on splash screen in release apk...

Comment: are you fetching any data from the internet? IF yes, have you added the internet permission to the android manifest file?

Comment: Internet permission is there in the manifest file....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem by

`flutter build apk --no-shrink --split-per-abi`

Don't know why, but I think code default shrinking was the problem.

Comment: This did not work for me, I had to downgrade to gradle 6.1.1 and buildtool 4.0.2

Answer (score 13):

## Permanent solution

A permanent solution to @Anirban Das answer is to edit your release `buildTypes` on `app/build.gradle` with `shrinkResources false` as the following:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using some Lottie files (from assets) on the splash screen (of flutter, not the native one).
Adding only `shrinkResources false` helped me resolve this issue in my case.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. This is happening with Flutter 2.2.3. I integrated a native SDK for ads after which the home screen stopped showing and the app is getting stuck on a black screen. Tried all of the above but none of them has helped resolve the issue

Comment: I'm facing kind of same issue. but this problem is happening in my case when an app is not used for some days(approx a week). is it gonna solve the problem?  or i have made some other mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:allowBackup="false"` tag inside your `<application>` object in your app manifest

Answer (score 0):

I used `flutter_native_splash` version `0.1.8` before and got the same issue, when i updated my `flutter_native_splash` version to `0.3.0` it works fine