# Infinite splash screen on android

Tags: android, flutter

In my project, I was using flutter `3.0.3`. Once I updated to `3.0.4` and updated dependencies, suddenly when I launched the app on `android`, the `splash screen` is showing `continuously`(never going to the main app). I tried by moving to my previous commit, `downgrading` flutter but to no avail.

This happened before but I luckily fixed it by upgrading kotlin `jdk` to 8(was 7 before).

I am using `flutter_native_splash` library. But it looks it doesn't have any impact on my project.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180892/flutter-android-release-stuck-on-splash-screen) question talks about `only release` mode. But, in my case it is happening both `release` and `debug` modes. I would really appreciate your help on this!

My main function:

```
void mainCommon() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) => options.dsn = Config.sentryDsn,
    appRunner: () async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
      final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> messengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
      await BlocOverrides.runZoned(
        () async => App(
          api: Api(Config.grpcChannel),
          database: await Config.db,
          appDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
          notificationManager: await NotificationManager.init(Config.grpcChannel),
          messengerKey: messengerKey,
        ),
        blocObserver: AppBlocObserver(errorCallback: BlocErrorHandler(messengerKey).errorCallback),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: can you share your main() function?

Comment: sure I have shared

Answer (score 0):

This is not for all cases. But, upgrading `firebase_core` and `firebase_messaging` could solve for some cases. In my case, it solved the problem for the first. But, once I upgraded all my other packages, it occurred again.

Android studio sucks. When I used Visual Studio Code, the exception was thrown in main where I initialised firebase. But in android, it ignored exception so I wasted a lot of time finding where the problem was.

To see the error in Android studio, you need to get mainCommon in try/catch bloc:

```
 try {
        await Firebase.initializeApp();
        await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
        runApp(App(
          api: Api(Config.grpcChannel),
          database: await Config.db,
          appDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
          notificationManager: await NotificationManager.init(Config.grpcChannel),
        ));
      } catch (e) {
        logger.e("Got exception in mainCommon: $e");
        rethrow;
      }
```